# Access products data in new view (Spree)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

Setting up a new ruby on rails website with Spree gem. I want to make a slider (horizontal) with products. But I can't access the products data in the view. How can this be done? Connect view to Product-controller, new view with link with index method that's accessing products?

Slider is already made. Only getting the data so I can style the view for the slider. I don't want to make changes in standard products view in spree.

Answer (score 0):

In the controller that renders your view, you cloud call the class [::Spree::Product](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/product.rb).

And then, you'll be able to get the products, save them in an instance variable and uses in the view.

```
@products = ::Spree::Product.all
```